# Real and Natural numbers in R

Tags: r, numbers

I am trying to create a function which takes in an inputs and outputs the factorial of the number. 
If the input to the function is a real number, but not a natural
number, round n to the nearest natural number and print a warning message alerting
the user to this behavior.

My questions is: How do I check if the input is real or natural number?

Comment: `is.integer` and/or `is.numeric`? As in: `is.integer(0.1)` returns `FALSE`; be careful with `as.integer(0L)` though. It will return `TRUE` (depends on your definition of natural numbers (in/ex)cluding zero).

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
myFactorial <- function(x){
    if (any(x %% 1 != 0 | is.na(x))) message("Not all elements of the vector are natural numbers.")
    factorial(floor(x))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom function

```
f <- function(x) {
  if (x<=0 | x%%1!=0) warning("Input is not natural number!")
  factorial(max(1,as.integer(x)))
}
```

**Example**

```
> f(3.5)
[1] 6
Warning message:
In f(3.5) : Input is not natural number!

> f(3)
[1] 6

> f(0.1)
[1] 1
Warning message:
In f(0.1) : Input is not natural number!

> f(-0.1)
[1] 1
Warning message:
In f(-0.1) : Input is not natural number!
```

Answer (score 0):

*"How do I check if the input is real or natural number?"*

We can use `as.integer`

```
is.natural <- function(x) as.integer(x) == x & x > 0
is.natural(3)
[1] TRUE
is.natural(0)
[1] FALSE
is.natural(1.5)
[1] FALSE
```